# Connect mysql database with django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am a begginer in django, i try to connect mysql database with django but when i write `python manage.py migrate` in cmd i see this error: `mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required yo have 0.9.3`
so i decide to upgrade mysql client using this command:`pip install mysqlclient --upgrade` and i get this output:
[image]
[image]
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq7Jn.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYGSQ.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8wzN.jpg

How to fix it?

Comment: You do know right, that you can use Django's build-in SQLite3 database?
If your application is using python's venv (Virtual environment), you also haven't activated the environment when I look at your pictures.

Comment: yes, i know but i want mysql

Comment: But have you activated your environment? (Assuming you are using a virtual environment for your app)

Comment: If you didn't do that, try typing this into the console:
`YOUR_ENV_NAME\Scripts\activate`
Where YOUR_ENV_NAME is the name of your virtual environment folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install using wheel

```
pip install wheel
```

Download the mysqlclient from

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

for python 3.X

```
pip install mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

for python 2.x

```
pip install mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

this error commonly occurs in windows if not install visual studio and other tools.if you work in Django + windows then install visual studio latest version.